# Will Microsoft Office Student expire after four years?

Tags: microsoft-office

Will Microsoft Office Student completely expire after four years or will the web functionality be disabled?

Does anyone know what "4 year subscription" really means?

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/productID.260246200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should mean 365 * 4, or 1460 days, which should show in your live account products. That being said, however, in the Terms and Conditions is this snippet:

> [PROGRAM AND OFFER DURATION](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/DisplayStudentTermsAndConditionsPage/)
>
> The Program shall continue until terminated by Microsoft. Microsoft
>   reserves the right to terminate, cancel or otherwise change the
>   Program and these Terms at any time and for any reason. Microsoft also
>   reserves the right to terminate, cancel or otherwise change any
>   specific offer made through or in connection with the Program at any
>   time and for any reason.

They also clearly state later in there that they reserve the right at any time to verify your enrollment in an institution, without that, you could be liable to reimburse them for the difference of what you bought and what you're eligible to have purchased.

So yes, you should have 4years but there is the typical legalese in there too.

Comment: So you have either 4 years or the remaining time you'll be in university. Whichever is shorter. Is that right?

Comment: @Imray - There is a fairly big gray area there, but I think you have to be an actual student at the time of purchase.  The license will still be 4 years.  Though they do allow you to buy a max of 2 licenses, and you can activate the second license after 3 years.  So looks like you could actually get 7ish years of use if you wanted it.  Buy it your first year, activate - activate the second one mid-Senior year.  They seem to imply that is okay, you can check for yourself at the link I posted to be sure I am reading it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2013 activates via your Windows Live account. Once you own MS Office University you can see the original date and the expiration date of your subscription.

To answer your question, both the desktop applications and the web functionality will expire after 4 years.